# How to obtain the index value from an indexed image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-figure

I have an indexed image loaded in MATLAB and if I use the data cursor, I able to obtain the X, Y,RGB and Index value of a particular point.

However, how can I obtain that particular index value if I have the X,Y coordinates without using the cursor?

the only command I have been able to come up with is:

i(X,Y)

but the output is not what I need.

So for example, in the image below, I want to extract the value of 45 given that I have the X,Y coordinates. What should be the command for it.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Use `indexed_image_data(Y,X)`.

Comment: Why is the output not what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the Index value using the output you get when you load the image, for instance if you store the image data in a structure called s:

```
s = load('clown')

s = 

          X: [200x320 double]
        map: [81x3 double]
    caption: [2x1 char]
```

Pixel values are stored in `X`, whereas the associated colormap is stored in `map`.

Since indices in Matlab are [row,column], the X and Y  values you are looking for can be accessed in X like this:

```
s.X(139,175)
```

which gives 45.

More information can be found [here.](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/02/03/all-about-pixel-colors-part-2/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However, in the image I am using, the I(259,300) value is 1014 and the map dimensions are 64X3 hence, I cannot get the value that I need. However, if I am going through the cursor, I can still get the index value. Do you know why is that?

Comment: mhh I don't understand how it's possible to get an index value of 1014 if the size of your colormap is 64 x 3. Can you show your code along with a screenshot of your image as you did in your question?